# Load testing tool for HTTP and JMS

Tags: xml, http, testing, load, jms

I am looking for a load testing tool / load generator for HTTP (Web Services) and JMS calls.

What would be a state of the art tools?

- a) a free product
- b) a commercial product

Answer (score 1):

[Apache JMeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/) will do both SOAP and JMS, plus a boat load of other protocols.

[image: JMeter 2.4 Built In Samplers]

Answer (score 0):

Eviware has created a very straightforward load generation engine that you can use in Conjunction with SOAP-UI to generate load against a webservice.  It's called LOAD-UI.  Note that SOAP-UI also supports construction and submission of JMS as well.

You can checkout SOAP-UI at: http://soapui.org/

Load-UI: http://loadui.org/

Here are details on how to use SOAP-UI with JMS: 
http://soapui.org/JMS/getting-started.html

I've used both of these tools and they're well done and well supported.  We found a defect in SOAP-UI that was patched and available in the nightly snapshot in less than a week.

Both tools have a free open source version so it seems to meet all your criteria.

Answer (score 0):

As of October 2013 Load-UI does not seem to support JMS via their "Soap-UI-Runner"-Activity. This is a bummer. Also, when using the free version of Load-UI, you can't use the agent feature.

We took a look at JMeter (http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/) and Grinder (http://grinder.sourceforge.net/).

They're both free to use and support agents to parallelize the load.